# To add loading svg image for async request api

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I want to add custom svg image in my code for loading till the response comes from api called.

I have tried adding flag but it's not working.

Please help me how can i add svg image for loading. I am in learning phase of react and redux.
I have processChatMessage for requesting the api call.

The reducer.js is like:

```
const processChatMessage = (state, action) => {
  console.log("[reducer]", action.type);

  const { messages } = state;
  const { message } = action.payload;

  const newMessages = [...messages, message];

  return { ...state, messages: newMessages };

};

const commitChatMessageRequest = processChatMessage;
const commitChatMessageSuccess = processChatMessage;
const commitChatMessageError = processChatMessage;

// Hub Reducer
const ChatMessageReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  let newState;
  switch (action.type) {
    case types["CHAT/MESSAGE_REQUEST"]:
      newState = commitChatMessageRequest(state, action);
      break;
    case types["CHAT/MESSAGE_SUCCESS"]:
      newState = commitChatMessageSuccess(state, action);
      break;
    case types["CHAT/MESSAGE_ERROR"]:
      newState = commitChatMessageError(state, action);
      break;
    default:
      newState = state;
  }
  return newState;
};


export default ChatMessageReducer
```

And the action.js is as below:

```
import types from "./action-types";

let isErrorMessage = false;
let onProcess = false;
let sender = 'Bot'
let error = null;

// action creator
export const msgChatMessageRequest = text => ({
  type: types["CHAT/MESSAGE_REQUEST"],
  payload: {
    message: {
      text,
      sender: "User",
      isErrorMessage
    },
    onProcess: true,
    error
  }
});


export const msgChatMessageSuccess = text => ({
  type: types["CHAT/MESSAGE_SUCCESS"],
  payload: {
    message: {
      text,
      sender,
      isErrorMessage
    },
    onProcess,
    error
  }
});

export const msgChatMessageError = error => ({
  type: types["CHAT/MESSAGE_ERROR"],
  payload: {
    message: {
      text: "Sorry! " + error.message,
      sender,
      isErrorMessage: true
    },
    onProcess,
    error
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new here, quick advise : just the "it's not working" is never sufficient. Really try to describe the expected behaviour (you did it) but also the current behaviour. For example here I have no idea of what is happening : it the **onProcess** set to true at anytime ? Is it just maybe a problem of you not succeeding to implement the image itself in your code ? ... So much possibilities.

Anyway I even do not see any call to an API in your code so again, it is difficult to see where the error is coming from...

**BUT** positive thing, I see that you had the good intuition to use an *onProcess* boolean in your store, I guess to track the state of your pending request.

Now the logic you need to implement is with 1 action and 3 reducers :

**FetchChatMessage** : First call **IsFetching** reducer to pass your *onProcess* to True, then call your API, then on answer call **OnChatMessageSucces** reducer if success, or **OnChatMessageFail** on failure and on each of these methods set your onProcess to false.

Here is a quick example of what you are actually trying to do : https://jsfiddle.net/ibobcode/fgk917bz/5/

    `.`